# VUE - chart.js failure

Tags: vue.js, github, charts, chart.js

am trying for several days to get charts into my vue project charts ... i tried almost everything ! chart.js vue-charts ... am using tutorials on YTB but everytime its not working .. can you somehow help me ? Am using Vue version @vue/cli 4.5.13

i just created

```
vue create project1
```

then get into  that project..
used `npm install chart.js`

everything gets installed right..
but after if i tried using those tutorials https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/getting-started/ there are lots of errors...

So can you somehow help me ? :D some YTB tutorial for dumbies

https://github.com/OutLandishnessSad/DaTest

Comment: Installing JS packages in Vue is a little bit different. Either you can create your own package to work with Vue or you can use already something someone has done. There is a package for chartjs to be used in vue https://vue-chartjs.org/

Comment: @null I would recommend against using vue-chartjs since it's still not updated to support chart.js V3 so you are better off to just implement chart.js itself barebone or make an own custom wrapper.

Comment: OutLandishnessSad can you share what kind of errors you get because it will make it a lot easier to help

Comment: @LeeLenalee Thank you. I havent noticed that